# php warning redirect

Tags: php, warnings, snmp

I use `snmp2_real_walk` function.

```
$tmp = snmp2_real_walk($ip, '***'.$vlan, $title, 100000,10);
```

When oid is correct and the device is working i get the desired output. But i want to handle warnings: `Invalid object identifier...` or `No response from 192.168.19.249...` or whatever. My problem is: how can i either redirect those warnings into my variable?

or is there some another function which shows these warnings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also have a look at [set_error_handler](http://php.net/set_error_handler) to set your own error handler for this specific case, and then restore the error handler after making the function call.

Comment: I doubt this will work, as set_error_handler just responds to E_USER type errors. one could get it done using register_shutdown_function and error_get_last.

Comment: but this works! it's much the same as `error_get_last` but seems more correct to me

Comment: @Raffael1984: `set_error_handler` responds to `E_WARNING` errors, which is what `snmp2_real_walk` triggers.

Answer (score 1):

using `error_get_last()` was the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at PHP's [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) function. snmp2_real_walk generates E_WARNING messages when it encounters an error, set_error_handler will allow you to capture these and log them etc.

Comment: I doubt this will work, as set_error_handler just responds to E_USER type errors. one could get it done using register_shutdown_function and error_get_last.

Comment: @Raffael1984: Actually, `set_error_handler()` handles *most* error types, not just `E_USER_*`. Notable exceptions are the ones that are logically impossible (e.g. parse or compile errors) and (unfortunately) fatal errors.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a try-catch block to catch your exception here's an example from PHP's documentation adjusted to your function:

```
<?php

try 
{
    $tmp = snmp2_real_walk($ip, '***'.$vlan, $title, 100000,10);

} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}

echo $tmp;
?>
```

The PHP Manual Page:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Comment: this works too, but i have to do double work here: once i cought an exception, i must than parse it