# Way to get OWN stderr output in PHP script

Tags: php, stderr

I googled a lot, but all articles I found are about how to write to `STDERR`, or how to get `STDERR` from other processes executed with `exec`, `shell_exec`, `proc_open`, etc...

But I want to know, how I can get my own script's `STDERR`?
(I write a web-frontend to my CLI script, and want to use all files as "black box" to capture `STDERR` and return `JSON` to the client)?

Comment: maybe this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731877/php-warning-redirect

Answer (score 1):

Create your own error handler and write the content wherever you want:

```
$log = array();
set_error_handler(function ($no, $str, $file, $line, array $context) use ($log) {
    $message = "$no: $str in $file on line $line";
    $log[] = $message;
    fwrite(STDERR, $message);
});
```

You could probably try to read from `STDERR` instead of writing to it, but I'm not sure how well that works.

Comment: I do not want modify source code of "black box". I want to capture STDERR.

Comment: You want to capture STDERR from the command line, not within the script itself?

Comment: I want to capture STDERR from script itself. For example, I have a lib, that outputs to STDERR, but I cannot(want) to change the lib to store output in some array, for example.